# Force needed to roll wheel over edge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

I'm looking to find F. See image below.

What we know:

- Mass of the wheel: $ m = 14 $ kg
- Wheel radius: $ r = 0.32 $ m

[image]

What I've tried so far:

$$ mg + N + \sin(38.7)k = 0 $$

Once the wheel just is about to roll over, normal force should be zero:

$$ N = 0 $$

And thus:

$$ mg = -\sin(38.7)k $$

Based on these caluclations I assumed I'd find F by

$$ F = -\cos(38.7)k $$

This didn't give me the correct answer. So I turn to you guys (mind you, I've tried different methods as well).

Comment: Are the angles given in degrees or radians ? We should confirm that first.

Comment: I calculated the angle based on the information I got. It's in degrees, I should have clarified.

Comment: Think about this in terms of a torque problem. In the method shown above, the distance of the force F from the center of the wheel isn't used. Intuitively, it should be easier to roll the wheel up (F at the radius) than push it up (F at the center). When the wheel rolls up, the wheel is rotating around the corner of the step, with the torque from F and the torque from gravity being balanced.

Comment: I actually tried that method as well. Basically, 0.32 x cos(38.7) x mg=F_p x 0.42, where F_p is the component of F which is perpendicular to the radius.

Comment: Please define 'k'. Seems like the normal force from edge on the wheel, but i'm not sure.

Comment: @Gaurav yes, that's correct.

Comment: @user1904218, the second part of the torque equation is F_p x 0.3. F is at a height of 0.42, but you want the height above the step (radius at which the force acts).

Comment: Okay, then Matt's method should work. It's the most straightforward solution I can think of. Are you sure you've understood the method correctly ? Check your calculations again too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Balance torques around the corner of the step, so  r x cos(38.7) x mg= F x 0.3.

F = 114 N

Comment: Looks like you found the answer. I am super confused now though. The reason I multiplied F_p by 0.42 is because it's the component of F that's perpendicular to the radius at which it acts.

Comment: Torque is a force acting at a distance around a point, so you have to look at not only the force perpendicular to the radius (which you've got), but what is that radius itself. The center of rotation is the corner of the step, so you need to find how far away from that corner are the vertical and horizontal forces. You got the torque from gravity just fine, which is the vertical force of gravity times the horizontal distance from the step to the center of mass. The torque from F is the horizontal component of F multiplied by the vertical distance from the step to F.

Comment: Appreciate the help. I kind of see why your solution works, and totally get what you mean. It's just that I'm confused why the radius shouldn't be 0.42 for the perpendicular component of F. Modified image to explain what I mean: http://i.imgur.com/TLPX955.png

Comment: F is acting at the top of the inner radius of the wheel. Note that the corner, the center of the wheel, and where the force is acting don't lie on a straight line - if they did, THEN the radius would be 0.42 and you could do what you're talking about. Since they're not, though, the radius of action of F_p is actually less than 0.42. If F_p acted where you're talking about, the arrow for F would be lower, with a radius of less than 0.3